# Find and Replace a particular Tab separated location in .NET string variable

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, replace

I have a string with TAB separated data. I would like to replace text at an arbitrary TAB position in the string.

E.g. I would like to replace a "N/A" with "-1.0" at the 5th split of TAB characters. I can identify the right section with string_data.split(vbtab)(4).replace("N/A", "-1.0") but I'm looking for an efficient way of changing this in the original string?

This seems to work, anyone got anything clever? LINQ?

```
Private Sub test()       
Dim input_string As String = "abc:abc:abc:abc:abc:N/A:abc:abc"
        Dim nth_loc As Integer = 5

        Dim ix_s As Integer = IndexOfNth(input_string, ":", nth_loc)
        Dim ix_e As Integer = IndexOfNth(input_string, ":", nth_loc + 1)
        Dim textBefore As String = input_string.Substring(0, ix_s + 1)
        Dim textAfter As String = input_string.Substring(ix_e)
        Dim textbetween As String = input_string.Substring(ix_s + 1, ix_e - ix_s - 1)
        Dim output_string As String = textBefore & textbetween.Replace("N/A", "-1.0") & textAfter
End Sub


    Private Shared Function IndexOfNth(str As String, c As Char, n As Integer) As Integer
            Dim s As Integer = -1

            For i As Integer = 0 To n - 1
                s = str.IndexOf(c, s + 1)

                If s = -1 Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            Return s
        End Function
```

Comment: Does it matter that the string you want to replace is at the n-th position ? If there's an "N/A" in 2nd position, you don't wan't to change it also ?

Comment: No in this case I only want to change in selective positions.

Comment: First, you data is `:` delimited, not tab delimited. Second use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) to split the string into an array, alter the *nth* item in the array and then use [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx) to reassemble it.

Comment: Hi, the : in this case was to make debugging easier.  @Matt thanks for the String.Join function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String is immutable, so you're not modifying the original string even with your current code.

> "*A String object is called immutable (read-only), because its value cannot be modified after it has been created*". [[MSDN : String Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Immutability)]

Therefore, I think using `.Split()` then `.Join()` is still better :

```
Dim input_string As String = "abc:abc:abc:abc:abc:N/A:abc:abc"
Dim nth_loc As Integer = 5
Dim split = input_string.Split(":")
split(nth_loc) = "-1.0"
Dim result = String.Join(":", split)
```

Another thing, LINQ is for query, not data modification. LINQ doesn't seems suitable to address this problem.